# Back when current view controller is not presented by segue. Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, back

I am trying to present VC2 from VC1 without using segue. It works. Then, I tried to use `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` to back but it does not work. I am wondering what is the code I should use to back from VC2 to VC1. Below code is in appDelegate.

**AppDelegate**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let VC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2") as! VC2
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
self.topViewController()!.presentViewController(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)

func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let MMDrawers = base as? MMDrawerController {
        for MMDrawer in MMDrawers.childViewControllers {
            return topViewController(MMDrawer)
        }
    }
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    return base
}
```

VC2

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers) // print([<MyAppName.VC2: 0x12f147200>])
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: print self.navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers and put a break point in backbuttonTapped method and update code accordingly

Comment: I tried to print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers). It prints [<MyAppName.VC2: 0x12f147200>]

Comment: Exactly , it wont back to previous screen because you are presenting a viewscreen and trying to back by using popviewcontroller that won't work , Use dismissviewcontroller it will back to previous screen.

Comment: It works. It is because I create a view controller on top of my old one, so I have to close it by using dismissviewcontroller. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah it is fine now . I answered your question with complete details  , Mark it correct if it correct . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Flow of your navigation :

Current Screen - Presenting A New Screen (Which itself embed within a navigation controller with vc2) so Popviewcontroller won't work .

If you present any viewcontroller then popviewcontroller wont work rather use dismissviewcontroller to come out previous screen .

Use This :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
```

Solved!
Thanks.